# How to format my HDD when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

How do I format the hard drive on my machine before installing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you get to the Installation Type screen, choose **Erase and install Ubuntu**.  And if you're comfortable, you can go into **Something else**, and you can manage partitions the way you want.

[image]

Click on **delete** to delete the existing partition first, and then click on New partition table.

[image]

After that highlight the created partition and click on add.  Create a partition with the shown mount point

[image]

but leave some space for a swap area

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this simply removes the partition tables and *doesn't* actually format the disk, at least in Ubuntu 19. You need to separately carry out a disk format first, which could take a lot longer than the entire 'erase disk and Install' installation.

Answer (score 3):

When you are installing Ubuntu, at the partitioning step, choose **Use entire harddisk**, and Ubuntu will format the entire harddisk for you, also creating a swap partition.

[image]

Comment: How do I get to this screen?

Comment: This screen is from the not graphiqual installer. You can found almost same terms and options in graphical one.