# Installing Ubuntu as the primary OS on multi-boot system

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I was thinking of downloading this to my netbook since I love the operating system.  How do I install it to override all my other operating systems so I just have ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format my HDD when installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157674/how-to-format-my-hdd-when-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

[Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) the install file (torrent is most reliable). Then install to a USB or DVD. Finally, during the install process, choose "Install" and then "Replace # with Ubuntu".

You can find full and detail instructions from [this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest).

Comment: Thanks so much for your speedy reply.  A couple of questions for you.

1. Where does the option come up in the install for replace or install?
2. Since I will be doing this with a USB what do you mean install it to usb?  Copy it over?

Comment: The option to replace or install comes up after a few screens once you've booted from the USB. You can't just copy it over, please see this link http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows in order to make a bootable USB from windows.